# Passing javascript var value to grails variable

Tags: javascript, grails

How can I pass a javascript value to grails variables. For example:

```
   var ert = 1;
   function test(){
   ert++;
   }
```

that function will be called if a button is click, does incrementing the variable. Now I want to pass this value to a grails variables or groovy variables that is being returned to the page. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you want to use this variable? what do you mean with 'returned to the page'?

Comment: I have an action such as def mypage(){ def inc = 0; [inc:inc]}. I want to copy the javascript value to the inc variable to which the mypage contains the function test()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden field to your form and when the button is clicked, modify that hidden element's value to be what you want sent to the server.

```
<button onclick="testFunction()">Click me</button>
<input type="hidden" name="inc" id="inc" value="1" />
<div id="testOutput">1</div>​

var ert = 1;
function testFunction() {
    var inc = document.getElementById("inc");
    ert++;
    inc.value = ert;

    //for demo only
    var testOutput = document.getElementById("testOutput");
    testOutput.innerHTML = inc.value;
}​
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qRSfM/)

Comment: what do you mean? can you please give atleast sample code for it? thanks.